# Correcting null values on bound ModelFormSet

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a app to manage book orders from some people, here is the model :

```
class Order(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book)
    qty = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

I also use a ModelFormSet to allow people to order several books at once. Although the form use initial 0 values for the "qty" field, I'm afraid some people will use an empty string instead of it.
So, what I want is to "convert" this Null entry to 0 before the form is processed (but after it has been bound, obviously)
I found the following solution:

```
def order(request, person_id):
    if request.method == "POST":
        # Hack to correct Null entries from user... TODO: find better way...
        posted_datas = request.POST.copy()
        for p in [k for k,v in posted_datas.items() if re.compile("qty").search(k) and not v]:
            posted_datas[p] = 0
        formset = BookOrderFormSet(posted_datas)
        if formset.is_valid():
....
```

It works fine, and I feel it will probably help someone in the same situation, but i'm wondering if there is a better/cleaner way to go...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**edit**
So you want to forgive user who deletes default 0 and leaves the qty field empty w/o providing any suitable number, by reseting the value of the field to 0 w/o showing him the error "qty is required"? Normally, better not to do this IMHO =)

But if you want, besides check-and-set it in view, you could also patch the clean method of form Field to not to raise exception for empty value but change it to the default instead. For example

```
from django.core.validators import EMPTY_VALUES

class SmoothIntegerField(IntegerField):
    def clean(self, value):
        if value in EMPTY_VALUES:
            value = self.initial # set to default value
        return super(SmoothIntegerField, self).clean(value)
```

*ignore following prev misunderstanding answer*

I don't think you need this extra work. Django form and models protects it well:

- empty string '' or totally absence of qty will not get passed because the qty field is required
- string which is not integer will not get passed because the IntegerField itself ensures coercion of nonempty value to integer
- even you don't use formset.is_valid to ensure above things, non-number such as null still cannot be in DB because there is constriction that qty column is not nullable

Comment: I know that, my point is that people who will use the form are really not used to computers and I don't want them to be confronted to an error message, instead, I want to "auto-correct" their mistake...

Comment: Exactly what I wanted... And even if I understand what you mean, I have to take orders from many begginer students and really don't want to let them be confused...

Comment: This being said, I just tried your method, and realized that my qty IntegerField actually comes from a FormSet which is based on a ModelForm... I had to override the auto generated field, setting it to SmoothIntegerField AND as required=False and then it worked !

Comment: Ah, yes. Its always harder to use a framework in an unintended way.